# Типизированные коллекции и их интерфейсы при работе с методами

Tags: c#

Если мы хотим из метода получить `List<T>` как правильно сделать:

1. `List<T> Method() {...}`
2. `IList<T> Method() {...}`
3. `IEnumerable<T> Method() {...}`
4. `ICollection<T> Method() {...}`

и почему?

Если мы хотим передать в метод `List<T>` как правильно должно быть:

1. `void Method(List<T> list) {...}`
2. `void Method(IList<T> list) {...}`
3. `void Method(IEnumerable<T> list) {...}`
4. `void Method(ICollection<T> list) {...}`

и почему?

P.S. В принципе интересует обе ситуации и для `public` и `private`. Вот Entity Framework генерирует методы c ICollection например. А много примеров, когда люди работают через IEnumerable. Почему так?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51860/discussion-on-question-by-bulson-------).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте разберемся. Сначала - возвращаемый из метода результат.

Во первых - по строгости интерфейсы (и лист) строятся от `IEnumerable -> ICollection -> IList -> List` (собственно реализация `IList`).

`IEnumerable` - перечисление, которое может не иметь конца, в которое нельзя добавлять элементы.

`ICollection -> IList` - коллекции, у которых строго заданное количество элементов, добавлять и удалять элементы можно, мелкие различия между ними обычно не существенны.

`List` - конкретная реализация интерфейса `IList`.

Ни один интерфейс не может гарантировать, что вернулся именно `List`. Поэтому, если вам надо из метода вернуть `List`, то именно с таким типом и должен быть метод.

---

А вот с передачей листа всё намного сложнее. Тут сильно важна предметная область.

Если это условно метод добавления элементов в лист - то только лист метод должен принимать.

Если метод сортирует лист, при этом не используя ничего специфического - вполне можно расширить действие на `IList`.

Если метод не трогает входящий лист, а формирует новый список из него - то на вход фактически можно подавать даже `IEnumerable`, впрочем, чтобы не получить что-то подозрительное можно сократить до `ICollection`.

Фактически, по той же строгости сортируете интерфейсы и смотрите, с которым из них метод ещё сможет работать.

---

Плюс ко всему выше сказанному - всё, кроме `IEnumerable`, смогут изменять обе стороны, как метод, так и тот, кто его вызвал. Это стоит учитывать и при входящем и при возвращаемом значении.

Comment: Спасибо, информативно. С вашего разрешения, я еще подожду, мало ли кто еще созреет на хороший ответ.

Comment: @Bulson на самом деле, вопрос у вас достаточно общий, чтобы на него хорошо ответить. Попробуйте сформулировать вопрос конкретнее, чтобы понять, в чём проблема.

Comment: Я как раз в общем и озабочен:) Как правильно делать нужно? Очень часто встречал и встречаю, что люди возвращают из метода `IEnumerable`, а сам я всегда возвращал, то что ожидал(хотел) - `List`, вот и созрел вопрос.

Comment: @Bulson пока вас устраивает лист - им и пользуйтесь. Таки в большинстве случаев эти заморочки нужны только в очень крупных проектах с кучей слоев и всякой фигней типа моков\тестов\etc.

Comment: хорошо, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Если мы хотим получить из метода `List<T>`, то и возвращать нужно `List<T>`. Тут как раз всё просто.

Вопрос обычно стоит в другом: что мы *должны* хотеть получить из метода? Важно ли нам, что метод возвращает именно `List<T>`, или нас устроила бы точно так же `ObservableCollection<T>` или допустим `T[]`? Если нам безразлично, какой конкретно тип возвращает метод, а нужен только список, имеет смысл закладывать требования послабее: ставить возвращаемым значением `IEnumerable<T>`. Или `ICollection<T>`, если нам нужно уметь и добавлять. Или `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`, если нам нужен лишь фиксированный список на чтение. И т. д.

Аналогичное соображение работает и для коллекций-аргументов.

Общий принцип — указывайте наиболее *слабый* тип из тех, которые вам подходят. Это даст вам свободу менять имплементацию метода, не ломая при этом код на клиентской стороне.

Общего рецепта раз и навсегда нету, потому что у каждого метода свои требования. Указывайте тип в зависимости от требований, а не по формальным критериям.

Comment: Хорошие рекомендации, спасибо.

Comment: @Bulson: Пожалуйста!